# time series - minimum differencing order needed to remove the trend

Tags: time-series

I was wondering how can I find What is the minimum differencing order needed to remove the trend in a time series?
I have a a times series and a TimeSeriesModelFit, which is SARIMA model. I want to find the minimum differencing order that I need to remove trend in my time series.

**UnitRootTest[Values[Differences[TS, 1]]]**

I was wondering if UnitRooTest is a right approach to find the differencing order? and if the order 0 is way higher than order 1, 1 would be the minimum differencing order needed.